# Spring REST Docs getting started

Tags: spring, spring-restdocs

Following the REST Docs getting started tutorial I unfortunately receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.<init>(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:52)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:47)
    at f10.innovation.ApiDocumentation.setUp(ApiDocumentation.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation$1.evaluate(RestDocumentation.java:59)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

For the following code:

```
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .alwaysDo(document("{method-name}/{step}/",
                        preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void index() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("_links.business-cases", is(notNullValue())));
    }
```

I think there a some problems regarding dependency injection. But I am unsure how to fix them.
Can you help?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the rest of your code?

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required`

This means you are not creating a web application context, so you need to configure this either in the web.xml or via a java configuration.

With java it's something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

   @Bean 
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
      return new HelloWorld();
   }
}
```

With XML and annotations, you have an XML file that your servlet loads, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <!-- bean definitions go here -->

</beans>
```

See here for the Spring docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: I am using a simple spring boot application. But I am unsure where to set this configuration to get spring-rest-docks to work.

Comment: I found the place for the configuration described by you: the following annotations were missing ```@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApiApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration```